# XML Request/Response Using PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm just doing a Front-End Dashboard for an ERP using PHP. Which is possible to integrate the ERP with XML Request and Response. The ERP URL would be something like `http://localhost:9000`. 
To fetch the Data from that ERP, I must send the XML Request to the ERP server URL in a particular Template (These details are given in the ERP integration Manual)

**XML Request Template:**

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>Data</TYPE>
    <ID>TrialBalance</ID>
</HEADER>

<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
            <EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
            <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

If I send this Request to the ERP server `http://localhost:9000` It would give a response like below:

**XML Response Template:**

```
<ENVELOPE>
 <DSPACCNAME>
  <DSPDISPNAME>Purchase Accounts</DSPDISPNAME>
</DSPACCNAME>
 <DSPACCINFO>
  <DSPCLDRAMT>
   <DSPCLDRAMTA>-49566060.80</DSPCLDRAMTA>
</DSPCLDRAMT>
  <DSPCLCRAMT>
   <DSPCLCRAMTA></DSPCLCRAMTA>
</DSPCLCRAMT>
</DSPACCINFO>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Now I Have no idea how to send the XML request to an URL and Capture this Response using php. 
I'm new to **curl** Where in curl I Know to send the Request but I have no idea how to receive this response store it and display it.
I'm sure if i capture this response and display it. I can parse the XML and get the values which I want from the ERP. I'm right now in the dark, can some one throw the light so that it could unlock my way to the next step.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: You would use CURL to go out and FETCH the data using PHP.  Do a little research on SimpleXML and CURL

Comment: Ya I can feed the XML to the URL using curl, the action happens, problem is I don't know how to capture the Response as Raw XML like I shown above. could you guide me using which php function its possible. so that i can do research on it.

Comment: I'm confused whether you're sending XML to your PHP application or if your PHP application is pulling the XML from outside.

Comment: Let me Clear you, I'm sending a XML Request from my PHP application to my ERP which is a desktop application capable of getting XML Request and Give the Response. Now I want to send Request to that ERP runs in `http://localhost:9000` using my PHP code and should view the Response provided by the ERP in my PHP application. I know how to request but don't have an idea to view that Response.